# Mejor solucion a este problema de arrays con java?

Tags: java, array, poo

estoy estudiando programación con Java y para practicar estoy haciendo unos ejercicios que vi en internet, el problema es que no tengo las soluciones y simplemente si veo que funciona pues sigo para delante. Pero en este problema, veo que podría haber soluciones más eficientes pero no consigo salir de mi solución debido a mi bajo conocimiento en programación por ahora.

Si alguien tiene tiempo y me puede ayudar para ver otro tipo de respuestas a este problema me va a servir muchísimo para estudiar.

**El problema es este:**
Escribe un programa que pida 5 palabras y las almacene en un array. A
continuación, las palabras correspondientes a colores se deben almacenar al
comienzo y las que no son colores a continuación. Puedes utilizar tantos arrays
auxiliares como quieras. Los colores que conoce el programa deben estar en
otro array y son los siguientes: verde, rojo, azul, amarillo, naranja, rosa, negro,
blanco y morado.

Dejo aquí mi código el cual me funciona pero quiero mejorarlo y ver otras opciones más rápidas o eficientes:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declaracion de variables
    String palabras[]=new String[5];
    String cPredefinidos[]= {"verde","rojo","azul","amarillo","naranja","rosa","negro","blanco","morado"};
    String colores[]=new String[5];
    String texto[]=new String[5];
    int color=0;
    int palabra=0;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    //Ingresa valores en el array
    System.out.println("Ingresa hasta 5 palabras y pulsa Enter tras cada una:");
    for(int i=0;i<palabras.length;i++) {
        palabras[i]=sc.next();
    }
    /*Comprueba si el valor es un color o una palabra,
     *  y los guarda en el array colores o texto segun corresponda,
     *   comprobando cada valor del array "palabras" con los valores del array de colores definidos "cDefinidos".
    */
    for(int i=0;i<palabras.length;i++) {
        if(Arrays.asList(cPredefinidos).contains(palabras[i])) {
            colores[color++]=palabras[i];
        }else {
            texto[palabra++]=palabras[i];
        }
    }   
    //Recorremos el array "colores", si tiene valores se copiaran en los primeros puestos del array palabras por orden de entrada.
    for(int i=0;i<colores.length;i++) {
        if(colores[i]!=null) {
            palabras[i]=colores[i]; 
        }
    }
    //Hacemos igual que el paso anterior pero con el array "texto" y copiando los valores a partir del ultimo color ingresado.
    for(int i=0;i<texto.length;i++) {
            if(texto[i]!=null) {
            palabras[color++]=texto[i];     
        }           
    }
        
    for(int i=0;i<palabras.length;i++) {
            System.out.print(palabras[i]+" ");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: No te preocupes por la eficiencia de tus programas en este momento. A medida que vayas aprendiendo y practicando, tu forma de programar irá cambiando.

Comment: Es más recomendable es que escribas código limpio. Es decir, legible y fácil de comprender.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el OP pide una revisión de código sin plantear un problema, error o duda específica. Su pregunta bien podría tener respuesta en [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo general donde debes poner más atención es lo que haces dentro de los ciclos y las asignaciones de memoria, y cuando se te juntan las dos cosas la atención debe ser todavía mayor.

La parte más crítica que tiene tu código es esta:

```
for(int i=0;i<palabras.length;i++) {
    if(Arrays.asList(cPredefinidos).contains(palabras[i])) {
        colores[color++]=palabras[i];
    }else {
        texto[palabra++]=palabras[i];
    }
}
```

Estás creando un `ArrayList` por cada repetición del ciclo. Como son solo 9 elementos y 5 repeticiones no afecta mucho, pero imagina que fueran muchos más elementos y 100 mil o 1 millón de repeticiones.

Tienes 2 opciones:

- Trabajas con el `ArrayList` directamente desde el inicio.
- Haces la búsqueda tú mismo directamente sobre el array.

Yo elegiría la segunda porque lo único que necesitas hacer es buscar un elemento en el array. Si necesitaras hacer tareas más complejas que ya están implementadas en los Collections entonces sí tendría sentido hacer la conversión.

También podrías ahorrarte los arrays auxiliares si en cambio llevas 2 índices que vayan marcando la posición actual, uno para los colores y el otro para los no colores. Y sin arrays auxiliares te evitas tener que recorrerlos después para pasar las palabras al array final.

Aquí te dejo mi solución ya que lo que quieres sobre todo es comparar y ver otras formas de hacerlo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba {

    private final static int PALABRAS = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] colores = { "verde", "rojo", "azul", "amarillo", "naranja", "rosa", "negro", "blanco", "morado" };
        String[] palabras = new String[PALABRAS];
        int cabeza = 0;
        int cola = PALABRAS - 1;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingresa hasta 5 palabras y pulsa Enter tras cada una:");
        for(int i = 0; i < PALABRAS; i++) {
            String palabra = sc.next();
            if (estaEnElArray(palabra, colores)) {
                palabras[cabeza] = palabra;
                cabeza++;
            } else {
                palabras[cola] = palabra;
                cola--;
            }
        }

        System.out.print(String.join(" ", palabras));
    }

    private static boolean estaEnElArray(String palabra, String[] array) {
        for (String s : array) {
            if (s.equals(palabra)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad que se ve mucho más claro y sencillo y sin duda se usa menos código y se da menos vueltas a los bucles. No había caído en usar un método para comparar la entrada de Strings con el array de colores, eso simplifica mucho.